# Alv grid column length display difference by User

Tags: abap, alv

Dears,
I have a ALV Report using REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY

User A use filter button on column 1
the column length is 10, but he can only input 2 length
but User B don't have this problem

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: seems like difference btw [regional settings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sap/sap_end_user_customization.htm) of these users